# Can I somehow define what can be the indexed name in the interface based on another interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-generics

I have this `interface`:

```js
export interface FieldContainerInterface {
  [key: string]: FieldInterface;
}
```

I want to define the `key` string based on an other interface. The I wish to use something like this:

```js
interface FieldContainerInterface<T> {
  // in here how can I pick the fields from <T>?
  [T<key>: string]: FieldInterface;
}

interface BanknoteInterface {
  id: number;
  deviza_id: number;
  value: string;
}

class Banknote implements BanknoteInterface {
  id: number;
  deviza_id: number;
  value: string;

  fieldContainer: FieldContainerInterface<BanknoteInterface> {
    // here I MUST to define id, defiza_id and value fields
  }
```

Can I somehow define what can be the `key` string in the `FieldContainerInterface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but one way to constraint keys to certain values is to use the `keyof` operator. [Here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/keyof-and-lookup-types-in-typescript) is a good article about it. Example:

```
import React from 'react';

interface BanknoteInterface {
  id: number;
  deviza_id: number;
  value: string;
}

type FieldContainerInterface<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]?: any;
}



class Banknote implements BanknoteInterface {
  id: number;
  deviza_id: number;
  value: string;

  fieldContainer: FieldContainerInterface<BanknoteInterface> = {
    // optionally add any key
    value: "hello",
    // id: 5,
    // deviza_id: 5
  }
}
```

Documentation:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) for this:

```
type FieldContainerInterface<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: FieldInterface;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?strictNullChecks=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwJIDtgQE4DMCGAxtALxQDeAvgNwCwAUA3JjgcVAEL7oDW6A9lgxY8RaOQZQocZAC4o6AK4BbAEY469KcggA3OAC98AfRnylajZKi78iRRHkBnYNmYBzTZQYNQkWAgoAML8mPjMOMKsYgA8ACoAfFBkElpQANo8ECDS6FBZIPy4UHEAuvLwSGgsosRePvSEiPhOTpzcfILQcMpgiBDKEJhtXLwCQjVs4tZmCirq2JraeoYmsxYLSzZ2Ds6uHprWuIHIIWER2BUnZ8Dh6JGTsaOdEyJTSSnWUgD031AAFjhoKgoABZACqAGU4lBgPwoDpjvdpMgADQIiDHIymZBQbi42z2aDHKpOazeeiUIA)